# Can you spellburn multiple ability scores in the same casting?

Tags: spellcasting, ability-scores, dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg

Let's say a wizard is casting a spell, and they spellburn 5 points of Strength, and 5 points of Stamina, for a total bonus of +10 to their spell check.

Is this scenario possible given RAW? The rulebook is vague. The only evidence I can find supporting either stance is this:

> Automatic criticals: There is one additional option for spellburn. A wizard who sacrifices a full 20 points of ability scores in one fell swoop automatically treats his next spell check as a roll of natural 20.

In DCC, the highest an ability score can be normally is 18. This seems to imply that a wizard can spellburn from multiple ability scores at once. If they couldn't, this rule could only ever apply in the incredibly rare circumstance a character has 20+ in an ability score.

I would really like to know if there is a more official ruling than my guesswork. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Anecdotally, I can say that burning multiple attributes at once was always how I have played at my tables, as the exact scenario you described (sacrificing 20 attribute points at once) has come up. While I can't find any specific rules directly stating that you can burn multiple stats at once, I did find this line in the Spellburn section of the Azi Dahaka Patron entry, emphasis mine.

> Azi Dahaka craves a boon of the caster. Within
> 24 hours of the spellburn, the caster is struck by
> a burning fever. The caster loses the spellburned
> **attributes** while in the grip of the fever and sees a vision of his master’s desire.
> -P.332

Many other references to resources consumed via spellburn use the phrase "attribute points", which isn't very helpful for answering this question. However, this passage uses the word "attributes" plurally. In my opinion, this is explicitly stating that you can burn multiple attributes at once.